# Search multiple words with hyphen

Tags: php, search

I am trying to search in MySQL database some French cities.

Some cities are like **SAINT-MALO** with an hyphen ( - ) inside .

My research is only with one word and when i write ( input type ) **saint-m** , the result is ok .

But when i write **saint malo** ( two words ) it's not working ( i mean nothing from ther rows researching )

What is the best way to do this

My code ( this only concerns the **city_upper** search not zipcode )

```
$list = array();

$strQuery = "SELECT zipcode CodePostal, city_upper Ville FROM french_cities WHERE ";

if (isset($_POST["codePostal"]))

{
    $strQuery .= "zipcode LIKE :codePostal ";
}
else
{
    $strQuery .= "city_upper LIKE :ville ";
    
    
}

if (isset($_POST["codePostal"]))
{
    $value = $_POST["codePostal"]."%";
    $query->bindParam(":codePostal", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
else
{
    $value = utf8_encode($_POST["ville"])."%";
    $query->bindParam(":ville", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$query->execute();

$list = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "AutoCompletionCPVille");;

foreach ($list as $row){
$row->Ville = ($row->Ville);
}

echo json_encode($list);
```

I try to find anwsers but i m novice in PHP . i guess i have to **explode** the research but not sure

Thank you in advance for your valuable help
rosebud

Comment: Simply look for both `SAINT-MALO` and `SAINT MALO`. In other words: Check if there's a space in `$_POST["ville"]` and if there is add an extra condition in the query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , what you mean by " extra condition" ?  in my $row() i have ONLY SAINT-MALO stocked to the database . if the user write SAINT M ( for exemple ) it could work with condition ?

Comment: Why are you using `utf8_encode()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the simplest way to do what you're asking is just to compare the strings after replacing all hyphens with spaces.

Change

```php
$strQuery .= "city_upper LIKE :ville ";
```

to

```php
$strQuery .= "REPLACE(city_upper, '-', ' ') LIKE :ville ";
```

and change

```php
$value = utf8_encode($_POST["ville"])."%";
```

to

```php
$value = utf8_encode(str_replace('-', ' ', $_POST["ville"]))."%";
```

Comment: Thanks you Olivier !  it work fine now .  utf8_encode was fot the french char ( é à ... ) .

Comment: @Rosebudwells Is your HTML page encoded in ISO-8859-1? I doubt it. And even if it is, [`utf8_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) is now deprecated, so you should not use it anymore.

Comment: yes my HTML encoded is <meta charset="utf-8" /> i need to change it by ISO-8859-1?

Comment: https://www.php.net/utf8_encode converts *from* ISO-8859-1 *to* UTF-8.  If your incoming data is already UTF-8 then you probably don't want to do this

Comment: @Rosebudwells To be explicit: remove the call to `utf8_encode()`.

Comment: ok thank i will remove the encode ,  you very much for your reply .